Expressing ideal sheaf of effective Cartier divisor as product of two ideal sheaves
If on a scheme, ideal sheaves $\mathscr{J}_1 \cdot \mathscr{J}_2 = \mathscr{I}$, where $\mathscr{I}$ corresponds to an effective Cartier divisor, is it necessary that $\mathscr{J}_1,\mathscr{J}_2$ both correspond to effective Cartier divisors?
As a special case, if $\mathscr{J}^2=\mathscr{I}$, where $\mathscr{I}$ corresponds to an effective Cartier divisor, is it necessary that $\mathscr{J}$ corresponds to an effective Cartier divisor?
Here product is understood as product of ideals, instead of tensor product of sheaves.
If it is in general false, are there conditions such as Noetherianess we can apply to the scheme to make it true?

Yes, this is true in general: see the answers here - two prove this in the case of a local ring, while another (mine) shows this in the case of a general ring. (If these answers fulfill your question, please let me know, or if they don't, please let me know what's missing.)

@KReiser Thanks, that's very helpful! I am trying to show the blow-up of I and I^2 are the same by universal properties, which needs this result of commutative algebra.

Great, glad to help.
